# How to remove loop

Tags: python, discord.py

I made a discord bot where if you sen't something in a specific channel, it will DM the server owner. It's like giving a request, but, when it goes to a verification where you need to type the code to the request channel, it works but it the bot thinks that the code is a request. So how do I fix this

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from random import randint

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',', intents=intents)

bottoken = open("token.txt", "r")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    cap = str(randint(1, 69420))
    if str(message.channel) == "request" and message.content != "" and message.content != message.attachments:
      await message.author.send("Hello this is a verification to avoid spam,please input this number on the request channel : " + "**" + cap + "**")
      def check(m):
          return m.content == cap

      msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
      await message.guild.owner.send(message.author.display_name + " requested for " + message.content + ".".format(msg))
      await message.channel.purge(limit=1)

client.run(bottoken.read())
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? I dont understand the relation between your question title and question text and code. What are you trying to do? What have you done and what more is expected?

Comment: @Ceres the code has loop bug where the bot thinks that the verify code is a request. I'm trying to make a bot that DM's the owner, like when I typed testing it gets sent to the owner. I did manage to do it but it's on an infinite loop wherein the bot thinks that the captcha code (to prevent spam) is a request.

Comment: Btw, `message.content != "" and message.content != message.attachments` are redundant. They will never return True

Comment: And you should close `bottoken` file at some point (I recommend using a context manager instead)

Answer (score 1):

To prevent infinite command loops, we can simply ignore all bot messages.

```py
async def on_message(message):
   if message.author.bot:
       return
```